# How to display svg from url's as image source in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, svg

In WPF I'm using uri's as ImageSource for items in a list and it works fine except for url's thats is a .svg url.

I've tried using [Svg](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Svg). It works but the images are messed up and I had to download the file locally.

I also tried using [SharpVectors](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpVectors) didn't understand how to get it to work and got nowhere using the documentation.

This is my original code and it works for png, gif and jpg:

```
return new BitmapImage(new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute));
```

If would also like to have a solution that does not require me to download files locally first but using Stream or the uri directly.

Comment: PNG, JPEG, etc. are bitmap formats, i.e. raster images. SVG is vector graphics, which is not supported by BitmapImage.

Comment: Example: https://github.com/ElinamLLC/SharpVectors/tree/master/TutorialSamples/ControlSamplesWpf

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend CefSharp.Wpf for displaying SVG's images. It is chromium engine wrapped as WPF or Windows control.

I'm using it successfully to even play quite complex SVG animations.
This would give you possibility to show online image without downloading it.

For more details and samples please refer:
[GitHub CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp)
It is available as NuGet package. The only drawback might be memory footprint and necessity of maintaining browser engine process but beside this it is perfect.